# celery how to terminate and start again task

Tags: python, celery

I want to use celery to do something like this:
1. I send message to start task, task is starting
2. If in task some condition is true then task should be terminated (canceled) and "returned" back to messages queue that other worker can take and do it.

and now I don't know how to terminate task from worker function. I was trying to do something like that in this called function:

```
if condition == true:
    revoke(current_task.request.id, terminate=True)
```

and in app when message is send I was trying to connect signal 'task_revoke' in that way:

```
@task_revoked.connect
def do_something_when_revoke(terminated, signum, expired):
    do_something_here...
```

but it is not working for me good. So maybe You can help me with that and tell me what I'm doing wrong or maybe what is different way to do something like that :)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly an easier way to achieve this would be to implement that logic inside the task itself:

- You don't have to revoke the Task, just don't do anything in it
- Your Task can just submit a new, updated, Task to the Queue